# How to avoid overlapping in ggplot2 boxplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I want to plot the boxplot:

```
library("ggplot2")
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy))
p + geom_boxplot(aes(colour = drv))
```

but the boxplot showed overlapped within each class.
[image]

How can I add distance between boxes？

Comment: yes, adding position=position_dodge(1) does the trick...

Answer (score 2):

just try following variant

`library("ggplot2")
dodge <- position_dodge(width = 0.9)
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy)) 
p+geom_boxplot(aes(fill = drv),position=dodge)`

With `position=dodge` you can set the distance between boxplots
Hope this helps

Best

Pavlo